# How to avoid destroying app when an AdMOb banner is clicked?

Tags: android, admob

I am using AdMob banner adds in my game. When I click on the add, I want app to pause while the user is taken to the ad content.

What is happening is that the app is completely destroyed and onCreate is called when I go back to the app.

How to resolve this?

Comment: on clicking ads your app is go in background and android OS kill background app automatically if device have low memory.

Comment: do you have an error or something?

Comment: No there is no error. Also I noticed just now that the static variables of the activity are kept intact. The main effect is that the layout is redrawn - all dynamically added views are removed.